# Transferring large files using SFTP using linux bash scripts

Tags: bash, sftp

I am intending to send a huge file around 1+GB over to the remote side using SFTP. However, it seems to work fine in interactive mode(when I sftp@xx.xx.xx.xx and enter the password manually, then I key in the put command). But when I run it in shell, it always timeout.

I have set the client and server ClientAliveTimeout settings at /etc/ssh/sshd_config but it still occurs.

Below is the linux script code

```
sshpass -p "password" sftp user@xx.xx.xx.xx << END

put <local file path> <remote file path>

exit
END
```

The transfer of files takes 10 min when using interactive mode
when run using script, the file was incomplete based on filesize.

Update: Current transfer during interactive mode shows the small files went through but the big file was stalled halfway during transfer.

Comment: What if you use `scp` and use passwordless login (read about `ssh-keygen`)? This never gave me problems.

Answer (score 0):

I prefere lftp for such things

```
lftp -u user,passwd domain.tld -e "put /path/file; quit"
```

lftp can handle sftp too

```
open sftp://username:password@server.address.com
```